# How can I parse timezones in the format "UTC+01:00"

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to parse timezone descriptions in the following format: "UTC+01:00".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Use `strptime()` from `datetime.datetime`.</s>

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta as td
>>> t = datetime.strptime('13:56:30 UTC-04:00', '%H:%M:%S UTC%z')
>>> tz = t.tzinfo
>>> t
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 13, 56, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.td(days=-1, seconds=68400)))

>>> print(t)
1900-01-01 13:56:30-05:00

>>> tz
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400))

>>> print(t.astimezone(timezone.utc))
1900-01-01 18:56:30+00:00
```

<s>You have to consider that timezones involve dates though. [You cannot parse textual representations of timestamps with timezones without knowing what date this time is in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY), so the omission of the date (default 1900-01-01) is a *hack that could very likely break*. You need to inject the proper date.</s>

Use regex.

```
import re
from datetime import timezone, timedelta as td

def parse_tz(tzstr):
    p = re.compile('UTC([+-])(\d\d):(\d\d)')
    m = p.search(tzstr)
    if m:
        sign = m.group(1)
        try:
            hs = m.group(2).lstrip('0')
            ms = m.group(3).lstrip('0')
        except:
            return None

        tz_offset = td(hours=int(hs) if hs else 0,
                       minutes=int(ms) if ms else 0)

        return timezone(-tz_offset if sign == '-' else tz_offset)

tzstr = 'UTC+01:00'

parse_tz(tzstr)
```

Comment: Strictly, you *mostly* don't need to care about dates *in this case*, because `UTC+01:00` does not provide any DST rules. It's just a flat adjustment that's applied the same year-round. However, it could make a difference if it causes you to "wrap around" to the previous or following day (by passing midnight). OTOH, not having DST rules is probably wrong in the first instance, since quite a lot of countries do observe some form of DST. To fix that, you would have to collect something like an IANA timezone identifier, instead of `'UTC+01:00'`.

Comment: I agree. My point is that OP actually lost *a lot more information* than just the date. They have lost the entire DST rules, which means they basically cannot do nontrivial date arithmetic unless they're content to ignore DST transitions altogether.

Comment: The last time you placed gives me an error.
`NameError: name 'timezone' is not defined`

I think you meant to put `tz`

Comment: This does not answer my question. I have the time in UTC, I need the time in UTC + 3, for example.

Comment: The magic is in `t.astimezone(...)`. You should be able to figure out how it work. I converted to UTC+0, so you should be able to convert to UTC+n

Comment: Please modify your answer to correctly answer what I'm asking. Check the example in the question to see more clearly what I need to do

Comment: It does exactly what you need. I defined a custom timezone and I used one that is provided in the standard library. I won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just wanted to know if there was an easy way provided by the library to do so. I'll mark your answer as correct anyway because it is, but can you add a message in your answer saying that there's no direct way of doing this with the datetime module? Thanks